# Fails to get data list of from sharedPrefrence flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to save list of data when i press a button then i'm trying to access the data into other screen.but it throws error

Error i am getting

```
E/flutter (17394): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<String>'
E/flutter (17394): #0      SharedPrefrence.getCartItem (package:boon/Utils/SharedPrefrence.dart:26:5)
E/flutter (17394): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Sharedprefrence Class with Save List and retrieve list

```
Future<bool> setCartItem(List<String> list) async
  {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.setStringList("cartkey", list);
  }

  Future<String> getCartItem() async
  {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getStringList("cartkey") ?? '';
  }
```

in Button press

```
SharedPrefrence().setCartItem(cartdatalist);
```

Dummy data ininlitzed

```
List<String> cartdatalist=['TWA Cap','₹575','M','Red'];
```

InitState in other page to access the saved data

```
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Future listdata = SharedPrefrence().getCartItem();
    listdata.then((data) async {
      listdata = data;
      print(listdata);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the return type of `getCartItem()` function to `Future<List<String>>`. Also need to return an empty `List` when `prefs.getStringList("cartkey")` is `null`.

```
  Future<List<String>> getCartItem() async
  {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getStringList("cartkey") ?? [];
  }
```

And then access it like this.

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    List<String> listdata;
    SharedPrefrence().getCartItem().then((data) {
      listdata = data;
      print(listdata);
    });
  }
```

Comment: i tried this.but when i try to access the data it throws error like this `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<dynamic>'` @Jigar Patel

Comment: @MorbiusBlack try using *Future<List<dynamic>*

Comment: @MorbiusBlack, I've edit the answer to include the accessing part.

Answer (score 1):

```
Future<List<String>> getCartItem() async
  {
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
return prefs.getStringList("cartkey") ?? '';
}
```

other page

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  SharedPrefrence().getCartItem().
  then((data) async {
  listdata = data;
  print(listdata);
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort,your's worked too.@Johny Saini